# Javascript: Make calculator display result after clicking operator

Tags: javascript

in Javascript, i'm making a simple calculator. I would like for it to display the result of an expression not only after using the equal button, but also when clicking a new operator to start a new equation.

Example: 2 then + is clicked and stored as firstNum, then 3 is clicked and the output shows 5, which then replaces firstNum

```js
const btns = document.querySelector('.button');
const input = document.querySelector('#txtresult')
let btn = {
  zero: document.querySelector('#zero'),
  one: document.querySelector('#one'),
  two: document.querySelector('#two'),
  three: document.querySelector('#three'),
  four: document.querySelector('#four'),
  five: document.querySelector('#five'),
  six: document.querySelector('#six'),
  seven: document.querySelector('#seven'),
  eight: document.querySelector('#eight'),
  nine: document.querySelector('#nine'),
  add: document.querySelector('#add'),
  subtract: document.querySelector('#subtract'),
  multiply: document.querySelector('#multiply'),
  divide: document.querySelector('#divide'),
  dot: document.querySelector('#dot'),
  equal: document.querySelector('#equal'),
  clear: document.querySelector('#clear'),
}

let firstVal;
let secondVal;
let operator;

function storeNum(op) {
  firstVal = parseFloat(input.value);
  input.value = op;
  operator = op;
  return firstVal;
}

function storeSec() {
  secondVal = parseFloat(input.value);
  input.value = operate(firstVal, secondVal, operator);
}

const removeZero = () => (input.value === '0') ? input.value = '' : false;

const removeOp = () => (input.value === '+' || input.value === '/' || input.value === '*' || input.value === '-') ? input.value = '' : false;

function operate(x, y, operator) {
  if (operator === '+') {
    return add(x, y);
  } else if (operator === '-') {
    return subtract(x, y);
  } else if (operator === '*') {
    return multiply(x, y);
  } else if (operator === '/') {
    return divide(x, y);
  }
}

function click() {
  btn.zero.addEventListener('click', () => {
    removeZero();
    removeOp();
    input.value += 0;
  });
  btn.one.addEventListener('click', () => {
    removeZero();
    removeOp();
    input.value += 1;
  });
  btn.two.addEventListener('click', () => {
    removeZero();
    removeOp();
    input.value += 2;
  });
  btn.three.addEventListener('click', () => {
    removeZero();
    removeOp();
    input.value += 3;
  });
  btn.four.addEventListener('click', () => {
    removeZero();
    removeOp();
    input.value += 4;
  });
  btn.five.addEventListener('click', () => {
    removeZero();
    removeOp();
    input.value += 5;
  });
  btn.six.addEventListener('click', () => {
    removeZero();
    removeOp();
    input.value += 6;
  });
  btn.seven.addEventListener('click', () => {
    removeZero();
    removeOp();
    input.value += 7;
  });
  btn.eight.addEventListener('click', () => {
    removeZero();
    removeOp();
    input.value += 8;
  });
  btn.nine.addEventListener('click', () => {
    removeZero();
    removeOp();
    input.value += 9;
  });
  btn.divide.addEventListener('click', () => {
    storeNum('/');
  });
  btn.multiply.addEventListener('click', () => {
    storeNum('*');
  });
  btn.subtract.addEventListener('click', () => {
    storeNum('-');
  });
  btn.add.addEventListener('click', () => {
    storeNum('+');
    
  });
  btn.dot.addEventListener('click', () => {
    input.value += '.';
  });
  btn.clear.addEventListener('click', () => {
    firstVal = 0;
    secondVal = 0;
    input.value = 0;
  });
  btn.equal.addEventListener('click', () => {
    storeSec();
  });
}

function add(x, y) {
    const num = x + y;
  const rounded = Math.round(num * 1000) / 1000;
  return rounded;
}

function subtract(x, y) {
  const num = x - y;
  const rounded = Math.round(num * 1000) / 1000;
  return rounded;
}

function multiply(x, y) {
  const num = x * y;
  const rounded = Math.round(num * 1000) / 1000;
  return rounded;
}

function divide(x, y) {
    if(x === 0 && y === 0) {
    return 'no';
  }
  const num = x / y;
  const rounded = Math.round(num * 1000) / 1000;
  return rounded;
}

click();
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

button {
  font-size: 15px;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #8e8e8e;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 0 9px #999;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

button:active {
  box-shadow: 0 5px #666;
  transform: translateY(4px);
}

#split {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  margin-top: 12px;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 20px;
  flex-direction: column;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #DEDEDE;

}

#top {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#txtresult {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border: none;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: 'M PLUS 1p', sans-serif;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 10px;
  color: #8e8e8e;

}

#txtresult:hover {
  background-color: #bfbfbf;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-color: transparent;

}

#txtresult:focus {
  outline: 2px solid grey;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-color: transparent;
}

#buttons {
  display: flex;
  flex: 3;
  margin: 5px;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.button {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  margin: 10px;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 10px;

}

#reset {
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #8e8e8e;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 0 9px #999;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#reset:active {
  box-shadow: 0 5px #666;
  transform: translateY(4px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>

  <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
    <title>calculator</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=M+PLUS+1p:wght@400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id='container'>
      <input type='text' id='txtresult'>
      <div id='buttons'>
        <div class=row>
          <div class=button id='seven'><button>7</button></div>
          <div class=button id='four'><button>4</button></div>
          <div class=button id='one'><button>1</button></div>
          <div class=button id='zero'><button>0</button></div>
        </div>
        <div class=row>
          <div class=button id='eight'><button>8</button></div>
          <div class=button id='five'><button>5</button></div>
          <div class=button id='two'><button>2</button></div>
          <div class=button id='dot'><button>.</button></div>
        </div>
        <div class=row>
          <div class=button id='nine'><button>9</button></div>
          <div class=button id='six'><button>6</button></div>
          <div class=button id='three'><button>3</button></div>
          <div id='split'>
            <div class=button id='clear'><button>c</button></div>
            <div class=button id='equal'><button>=</button></div>
          </div>

        </div>
        <div class=row>
          <div class=button id='divide'><button>/</button></div>
          <div class=button id='multiply'><button>*</button></div>
          <div class=button id='subtract'><button>-</button></div>
          <div class=button id='add'><button>+</button></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in you JS, this function made it work:

First I created the function `automaticResult`. It identifies when the operator and the firstVal variables are set. I do this because if this condition is true, the next pressed value is the second value, so we only need to call `storeSec()` to calculate and display the operation:

```
function automaticResult() {
    if (firstVal, operator) {
        storeSec();
    }
}
```

After this, you can pass this function to each numeric button in the script:

```
    btn.zero.addEventListener('click', () => {
        removeZero();
        removeOp();
        input.value += 0;
        automaticResult(); // <-- the function call here
    });
    btn.one.addEventListener('click', () => {
        removeZero();
        removeOp();
        input.value += 1;
        automaticResult(); // here too
    });
    /* the buttons from 0 to 9 has this function */
```

And then you just need to type the numbers in. For ex, if you press the button 5, button + and the button 5 again, it the second press of the button 5, it will display 10 automatically.

I hope that I helped you :)